# Datatable.net - server side processing parameters

Tags: c#, datatables

I am using datatable.net and the html code I have written so far is:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            "url": "Handlers/jQueryDatatableHandler.ashx",
            "data": { Operation: 'EmployeeList', searchText: '' },
            success: function (data) {
                json = JSON.parse(data);
                columns = [];
                // build column titles
                for (var i = 0; i < json.colnames.length; i++) {
                    columns.push({ title: json.colnames[i] });
                }

                var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                    "responsive": true,
                    "processing": true, 
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "order": [[4, 'desc']],
                    data: json.rows,
                    columns: columns,
                    columnDefs: [
                        {
                            targets: 0,                           
                            render: function (data, type, row) {
                                if (type === 'display') {
                                    return '<input type="checkbox" class="editor-active">';
                                }
                                return data;
                            },
                            className: "dt-body-center",
                            "orderable": false,
                            "searchable": false
                        },
                        {
                            targets: 1,
                            visible: false
                        },
                        {
                            targets: -1,
                            visible: false
                        }
                    ]
                });
            }
        });
```

jQueryDatatableHandler.ashx code

```
  public class DatatableInboxResults
  {
    public int draw { get; set; }
    public int recordsTotal { get; set; }
    public int recordsFiltered { get; set; }
    public List<string> colnames;
    public List<string[]> rows { get; set; }
  }

private string BuildDatatableResults()
{
    EmployeeListParameters mlp = new EmployeeListParameters();       
    mlp.numberOfRows = "10"; //not sure how to pass this value
    mlp.pageIndex = "1"; //not sure how to pass this value
    mlp.sortColumnName = sortColumnName; //not sure how to pass this value
    mlp.sortOrderBy = sortOrderBy; //not sure how to pass this value       
    mlp.searchText = searchTxt;

    DatatableInboxResults result = new DatatableInboxResults();
    result.colnames = new List<string>();

    result.colnames.Add(" ");
    result.colnames.Add("EmployeeId");
    result.colnames.Add("Name");
    result.colnames.Add("Title");
    result.colnames.Add("Joining");
    result.colnames.Add("Viewed");

    int totalRecords;
    int colCount = result.colnames.Count;;
    List<string> rows = new List<string>();
    result.rows = new List<string[]>();
    EmployeeViewerDataProvider mvdp = new EmployeeViewerDataProvider ();
    List<NEmployee> empList;
    msgList = mvdp.GetEmployeeDetails(mlp, out totalRecords);//subscriptionId, username, numberOfRows, pageIndex, sortColumnName, sortOrderBy,strText, out totalRecords);

    foreach (NEmployee msg in empList)
    {
        string[] row = new string[colCount];

        row[0] = "0";
        row[1] = msg.EmployeeId.ToString();
        row[2] = msg.Name;
        row[3] = msg.Title;
        row[4] = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(msg.TimeSent, tinfo).ToString();
        row[5] = msg.Viewed.ToString();

        result.rows.Add(row);
    }
    result.recordsTotal = (Convert.ToInt32(totalRecords) + Convert.ToInt32(mlp.numberOfRows) - 1) / Convert.ToInt32(mlp.numberOfRows);

    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);
}
```

This is working fine if I set serverside processing to false but when I make it true there are certain errors. Can someone please help me or suggest how to pass parameters in the code so it works fine.

Please advise how to do this.

Comment: Just a sidenote: Do you know [DataTables.Queryable](https://github.com/AlexanderKrutov/DataTables.Queryable)? I highly recommend to have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [DataTables documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side), "Server-side processing is enabled by setting the serverSide option to true **and providing an Ajax data source through the `ajax option`.**".

When I look at your code, I don't see you using this `ajax option`.

Besides, if you want to use Server-side processing, [you can initialize a DataTable instance as soon as your document is ready instead of having inside of an ajax success callback](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side). Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "Handlers/jQueryDatatableHandler.ashx"
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id').DataTable({
        destroy: true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "processing":true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "your url",
            "type": "POST",
            "data": {}
        },
    });
});

Comment: Explaining the answer is very helpful.